# How to view the database tables in application servers?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, eclipselink, wildfly

I'm writing Java objects to the built in database using JPA methods like `EntityManager#persist` and `persist`. The entity is now stored in a table database. How can I view the contents of the database? I want to see how the object graph was mapped to tables, check how much storage it takes, and so on.

I'm using Wildfly 10.1, Hibernate or EclipseLink and whatever the default database is. I looked in the management console but didn't find the tables. I'm not looking for a software recommendation, tutorial etc. Just for steps to view the database.

Comment: wildfly management console wont show you entries from DB table. To check DB table entries you have to use some third party tool or you can write your own java base application which will pull data from DB

Comment: @AbhijitHumbe Is it the same for other application servers?

Comment: I am not sure about WAS but weblogic console also didnt support this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently impossible to view the database through Wildfly or any other built in means in the IDE.